# Change in MSSQL Ordering

Tags: sql-server

We have a customer that has stated server maintenance was done (server name was changed) and they found that after the change, the ordering of a specific template (which reads from SQL views) has changed.  They have two databases, one where the maintenance was not done and then one where it was done.  The trace shows exactly the same select statement on both (expected as no code change was done), but the results are ordered differently.

The select is as follows:

```
SELECT xxx
FROM VVMVOYAGEPORTSPLIT JOIN VVMVOYDASTATUSLOOKUP ON VVMVOYAGEPORTSPLIT.ACCOUNTSTATE=VVMVOYDASTATUSLOOKUP.ID 
                         JOIN VMVOYAGE ON VVMVOYAGEPORTSPLIT.ID=VMVOYAGE.ID 
                         CROSS JOIN SSLCLIENTCONFIG 
                         WHERE (SSLClientConfig.Description LIKE 'Enable State Fields' 
                         AND   SSLConfigModule LIKE 'VMVOY') 
AND (VMVoyage.ID = 20145087)  
ORDER BY vVMVoyagePortSplit.Sequence
```

So there is explicit ordering on the Sequence column.  On the server where no maintenance was done, the results will always come out as:

[image: Working]

So even though there is no order by on the Type column, C always came out before P.

Now on the server where the maintenance was done, the Type column is not consistent.

[image: Not working]

So I am curious what could cause the ordering to change?  I understand that I can just add the additional order by of Type to the select, but I would love to understand what can cause this.

Comment: Your query doesn't match the images you provided.  Anyway, you are ordering by sequence and probably that is A10Sequence column. It looks right in both images. There is no order by for the column where it says P, C. SQL server doesn't give any guarantee on the ordering of columns that are not contained in order by.

Comment: Hi - thank you.  Yes I have just marked xxx for all the columns, as there were plenty listed.  The two images sorts consistently on A10Sequence, as expected.  But on the one you will see that it also ordered correctly on A9Type, but on the other one not.  So when you say that the ordering cannot be guaranteed, what do you think could be the difference in SQL between these two?  I fully understand the fix, I am just trying to explain why it's different if the select is exactly the same between the two databases/servers.

Comment: One of them might have different clustered index, or different insertion order. As I said ordering is not guaranteed, and there is nothing like "ordered correctly" without having it in order by.

Answer (score 2):

You were lucky to have made it this far. Query order beyond what is specified in an `ORDER BY` clause is **NEVER** guaranteed. Databases are based on relational set theory, where tables are formally defined as **unordered** relations, and the views that then depend on those tables are no different. It is never okay to rely on query order without an explicit `ORDER BY`, and adding the full ordering to the query is the only appropriate fix here.

Things may *seem* to be stable for a time, but this was just because it was convenient for server performance. However, *lots* of a things can impact this. One example is upgrading to Enterprise Edition enables a feature where performance is improved under load for one query by piggy-backing on disk reads for the same index already in use for another query. In this situation, the query can start returning rows in the middle, and then only needs to do additional disk reads after the prior query finishes for the pages that prior query had already finished. Changes in indexes, joins, table partitioning, and numerous other things can also impact query order... *unless* the full `ORDER BY` clause is provided.